# stl thread аналог waitforsingleobject

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать средствами stl следующую вещь:

1. работают 10 потоков
2. после того, как заканчивают выполнять поставленные для каждого потока задачи первые 9 закончивших ожидают когда закончит последний свою задачу

в WinAPI я бы использовал обычный `WaitForSingleObject`, но как аналогично сделать это с помощью `stl thread`?

т.е. имеется примерно такой код:

```
void thread_func(std::mutex& lock) {
    while (true) {
        // основные вычисления
        my_calculate();

        // отчитываемся о завершении работы
        lock.lock();
        m_actual --;
        lock.unlock();

        if (m_actual == 0) {
            // определить новое вычисление
            my_prepare();

            // сказать всем процессам, которые раньше справились с задачей - работать снова
            set_event();
        }
        else {
            // ждем когда разрешат работать :)
            waitforsingleobject();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C++11 обязательно? В C++20 подвезли [`std::latch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/latch) как раз для этого.

Comment: устроит и C++20!

Comment: Значит `std::latch`. А на C++11 можно попробовать что-то на `std::condition_variable` сообразить.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, вот с этим `std::condition_variable` я и мучался и что-то я видать неправильно понял его работу ибо ничего не получалось :( , сейчас посмотрю примеры `std::latch`